# Centering content with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a small landing page at http://www.saleshuddlegames.com

on the desktop everything is fine but when I start using tablets and smartphones, everything starts going out of alignment. I can't seem to make anything centered.

Specifically look at my .footer

```
<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 centered">
                <ul class="social navbar-nav">
                    <li class="social-item"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/saleshuddle" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-item"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/saleshuddle" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-item"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/saleshuddleacademy" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-3x"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="social-item"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/saleshuddle" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="copyright col-md-6 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">
                <p>&#169; 2013. The Training Game is property of <a href="http://www.thesaleshuddle.com" target="_blank">Sales Huddle Group, Inc.</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I used a centering snippet from a previous post:

```
.centered {
float:none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any Ideas??

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot? It looks fine for me so far when I resize the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`text-center`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-emphasis) class from bootstrap?

I've juggled the selection of columns for the social icons, and removed them all for the copyright text.. now this looks good here at all browser sizes:

```
<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <ul class="social navbar-nav">
                <li class="social-item"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/saleshuddle" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i></a></li>
                <li class="social-item"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/saleshuddle" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></a></li>
                <li class="social-item"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/saleshuddleacademy" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-3x"></i></a></li>
                <li class="social-item"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/saleshuddle" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="copyright text-center">
            <p>© 2013. The Training Game is property of <a href="http://www.thesaleshuddle.com" target="_blank">Sales Huddle Group, Inc.</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```